# How remove lines which are not equal in two buffers?

Tags: text-editing, text

Consider the following buffers

buffer_1:

```
11111111
22222222
33333333
44444444
```

buffer_2:

```
55555555
66666666
22222222
44444444
```

I need to remove **all lines which are not equal** in buffer_1 and buffer_2.
The resulting **buffer_3** must only contain equal lines, i.e.
**buffer_3** must be like this

```
22222222
44444444
```

The lines which where NOT EQUAL and are removed from buffer_2 are

```
55555555
66666666
```

Is it possible in Emacs?

Comment: `comm -12 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)` should work too (see this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2696055).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble not work for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the following I assume that the order of the lines in the result buffer is irrelevant.

For medium size buffers you can use `cl-intersection`:

```el
(defun txt-intersection (buffer-a buffer-b)
  "Only keep the set theoretic intersection of lines in BUFFER-A and BUFFER-B."
  (interactive "bBuffer A: \nbBuffer B: ")
  (with-current-buffer (generate-new-buffer (concat (buffer-name (get-buffer buffer-a))
                            "∩"
                            (buffer-name (get-buffer buffer-b))))
    (insert
     (mapconcat #'identity
        (cl-intersection
         (split-string
          (with-current-buffer buffer-a (buffer-string))
          "\n")
         (split-string
          (with-current-buffer buffer-b (buffer-string))
          "\n")
         :test #'string-equal)
        "\n"))
    (display-buffer (current-buffer))))
```

The second case is the analogous with `intersection` substituted by `set-difference`.